# Symfony Form - sorting data by changing sort option in dropdown list

Tags: symfony, sorting, doctrine, symfony-forms

I'm sorry for the title but I don't know how to define it good. I'd like my app to sort data (in Doctrine) depending on the sort option which user select it in form dropdown list.

The data I mentioned above are stored inside my Doctrine Entity which I called it `Flashcards` and the `Flashcards` Entity contains properties which them must be sorted by option that user select in dropdown. `Flashcards` Entity looks like the following (I gave only a few properties for simplicity):

```
/**
* @ORM\Id()
* @ORM\GeneratedValue()
* @ORM\Column(type="integer")
*/
private $id;

/**
* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Words", inversedBy="flashcards")
* @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
*/
private $words;

/**
* @ORM\Column(type="datetimetz")
*/
private $creation_date;
```

Now the controller's code for form is usual, like the Symfony Doc say:

```
// code for form inside FlashcardController
$flashcard = new Flashcards();
$form = $this->createForm(FlashcardType::class, $flashcard);
```

And inside `FlashcardController` *render()* method I call *createView()* method on `$form` object.

The form code is placed inside `FlashcardType` class and contains code for mentioned above dropdown list and its options. It looks like this (for simplicity I gave only the methods):

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('sortBy', ChoiceType::class, [
            'label' => 'Sort by',
            'choices' => [
                'Date increase' => 1,
                'Date decrease' => 2,
                'Word alphabetically' => 3,
                'Word not alphabetically' => 4
            ]
        ]);
}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'data_class' => Flashcards::class
    ]);
}
```

So as you see the dropdown options include sorting by: date increase, date decrease, word alphabetically, word not alphabetically. User choose one of them in view. So manipulating data by user ***does NOT change value of this data*** represented by properties. Changing sort option in dropdown should change Doctrine query to sort by user-changed value. I have no idea how to achieve this in Symfony. Could you give me plese some tips how to make it?

Thank you in advance for answers!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you have a few options:
First: wire javascript / jquery to select input and submit the form when user changes order(it should reload the form applying the filter, you can set any data user used in the 'previous' page using RequestStack to get the form fields from request / query depending on the method)
Second: get all the nodes you display record and try to manipulate the order based on the select value every time user changes the value
Tell me if this is what you meant else correct me and I'll try to provide the answer

Comment: Thank you for answer! `get all the nodes you display record and try to manipulate the order based on the select value every time user changes the value` - that's exactly what I mean. I already have a Doctrine query in repository for `Flashcards` Entity and displayed records. The thing is I don't know how to make the guery dependent on sort value which user choise in this form. I'd like to achieve that in Symfony.

Comment: you can reload the records using AJAX, just make a request with paramemter { sortOrder: select.value }, then get that value in the controller(you can use a simple switch to get records based on the sortOrder variable) and then return the result as a response and load it to the page

Comment: Using AJAX is a good idea, thank you! But is there some way to do it by  Symfony only?

Comment: Submitting the form(with js) after every change and displaying filtered results based on the select value, you can check if the submit button was clicked or if the form was submitted by any other thing like this: $form->get('submit')->isClicked() (true if you clicked button, false if the form was submitted by any other way)